# Return short date string from property C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am trying to return ShortDateString from my property,

```
  public DateTime PICKDT
{
    get { return PICKDT.ToShortDateString(); }

}
```

Input data will be in this format `2041-04-30T00:00:00`.

Can any one point out the right way to do this?

Comment: `ToString()` will return a `string` but your property is of type `DateTime`.

Comment: You need a backing field and a method that returns a string.

Comment: That will still return a `string` :)

Comment: What do you mean by _Input data will be in this format_? You have a result as `2041-04-30T00:00:00` on your `DateTime` instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private DateTime _pickdt;
public string PICKDT
{
    get {return _pickdt.ToShortDateString();}
}
```